# Remove /disable item without scrollview

Tags: c#, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

How i disable item if without scrolview.

```
StackLayoutContent -> StackLayout(3button) (Position Start)
StackLayoutContent -> StackLayout -> ScrollView->StackLayout(25 button) (Postition Centar)
StackLayoutContent ->StackLayout(2button) (PositionEnd)
```

Problem is button in scollView exceed in other stack how disable ?

Comment: Have you tried the IsVisible property?

Comment: No, but I add color for orders stack and item without is not visible